# How to visualize shapes without grid lines with jzy3d?

Tags: jzy3d

I am visualizing several shapes with jzy3d with code like this:

```
chart.getScene().getGraph().add(new Sphere(pos, 0.05f, 5, Color.GREEN));
```

The sphere is shown but hslice/vslice lines are shown too. I want simply to show the shapes without these white lines.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution myself:

The shapes have the method:

setWireframeDisplayed(false);

which switiches the gridlines off.